# CSS валидатор ругается на calc()

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

я использую в своих стилях такие формулы для(размера шрифта, отступов и т.д.)

```
 font-size: calc(30px + (45 - 30) * ((100vw - 320px) / (1280 - 320)));
```

в итоге в [css-валидаторе](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) вижу ошибку

> Ошибка значения : font-size Ошибка разбора (1280 - 320)))

Comment: Скорее всего ошибка в том, что это числа, а не значения в пикселях.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 разве в функции calc нельзя использовать числа? Сейчас проверю

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 с пикселями тоже самое

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Похоже, валидатор не любит скобки, потому что если их сократить, то он пропускает

```
font-size: calc(45px * ((100vw - 320px) / 960));
```

---

Ещё предположение - кривой валидатор.
Никто другой не ругается оригинальное решение, а браузеры спокойно выполняют код.
Получается, что ошибки и нет вовсе, но не для валидатора.

Comment: очень странно. что ругается именно на последние скобки. Да и высчитывать в уме(калькуляторе) не особо хочется)

Comment: Отныне вы сырок в шоколадной глазури

Comment: @Voprositel, изначально ник и был придуман при употреблении глазированного сырка :D

Comment: @Вадим, кстати, если мой ответ помог, отметьте его галочкой как правильный)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 я пометил как полезный ответ, но все же он не совсем решает проблему. Может есть какой стандрт для css на котором основан валидатор, который запрещает использовать столько скобок). Т.к. в css работают оба варианта

Comment: @Вадим, скорее косяк валидатора

Comment: @zxcqwe как написано в документации [Делитель должен быть `<number>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/calc#%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81). Валидатор в css настолько придирчивый, что если там не цифра, а уравнение, результат которого является цифрой, все равно выдаст ошибку.

Comment: @eccs0103, вообще W3C много на что ругается, тут проблема либо того, кто тестирует (не указывает параметры в настройках), либо самого валидатора, возможно он кривой. Всё же там есть отдельный инструмент для [теста CSS](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_uri+with_options) и вот он уже не выдаёт всю пачку ошибок, которые и не ошибки вовсе.